# How to reduce PDF file size using javascript/react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a website using reactjs and i want to compress the PDF files which are more than 5MB size. I have tried on Windows 10/ Chrome/Firefox. Is there any way we can reduce the size of PDF using javascript or any React library?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Are you looking for FOSS solutions only? Also, 5MB is not that much to render normally. Maybe the issue is easier to solve on the viewer side. What do you use for viewing? What OS+browser?

Comment: You didn't answer my first question. You need to narrow down your question, see this to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @VipulPathak, Please provide the solution.

Comment: @TanviAgarwal Hi Tanvi, I used a package called **compress-base64** 
  (https://www.npmjs.com/package/compress-base64) to reduce the size.

Comment: No good response to this question yet, will post a response when I solve this.